# After upgrading from .NET 5 to .NET 7 and removing Newtonsoft.Json, DateTime values in API responses are different

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, json.net, system.text.json

I recently upgraded my project from .NET 5 to .NET 7 and removed Newtonsoft.Json by replacing it with System.Text.Json. After the upgrade, I noticed that DateTime values in the responses of my API endpoints are different from what I expect.

For example, I expect the DateTime value "2021-05-10T11:20:54" to be returned as "2021-05-10T11:20:54", but instead, it is returned as "2021-05-10T11:20:54Z".

Previously, I was using Newtonsoft.Json with the following code:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

However, after removing Newtonsoft.Json, I'm not sure how to achieve the same behavior with System.Text.Json. How can I configure System.Text.Json to handle DateTime values in a similar way, or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

This problem also affects my Automation tests. I'm running automated tests, and this difference in DateTime values is causing failures in my tests. How can I address this discrepancy to ensure my tests pass as expected?

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, the "Z" at the end has a special meaning. It means "UTC". Without it your value has no time zone information. Is this truly what you want? It's common practice for date/time values to include Z at the end.

Comment: You might want to rethink if going Net 7 is the jump forward you want to make. There is a Net 8 already and that one is a LTS version.

Comment: I need to Net7 actually I want to do this. Because my automated tests fail, my other projects may get the wrong answer when they arrive at my .net7 project. I'm trying to fix this. I'm wondering why the dates change this way if there are no other options to fix this?

Comment: I would say you don't want to fix it. You want to break it again so that your tests still work and you can go on being ignorant to time zones. Rather fix the tests and your APIs behavior. The 'Z' here is a good thing and your previous behavior was a problem.